# При попытке распарсить html страницу с помощью jsoup включается ограничение доступа, но из браузера она открывается нормально

Tags: java, html, парсер, jsoup

Я хочу распарсить страницу и вытянуть оттуда определенную информацию. Проблема в том, что если повторить эту процедуру несколько раз (не в цикле несколько сотен раз за минуту, а просто 5-6 раз в течение нескольких минут) то вместо этой страницы начинает парситься другая, с сообщением: "C вашего IP-адреса поступило необычно много запросов. Система защиты от роботов решила, что c данного IP запросы отправляются автоматически, и ограничила доступ."

Причем из браузера я все так же спокойно могу заходить на этот сайт и переходить по ссылкам хоть сотню раз подряд, никаких блокировок не выскакивает.

Вот упрощенный код:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.kinopoisk.ru/film/328/")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36")
                    .referrer("https://www.kinopoisk.ru")
                    .get();
        System.out.println(doc);
        System.out.println("https://www.kinopoisk.ru/film/328/");
```

Я специально вывел результат в консоль, чтобы посмотреть, какой html код выдает. Потому-что если просто переходить по ссылке, то всегда выдает нормальную страницу, страница с сообщением об ограничении появляется только при парсинге.

В общем, серьезной проблемы в этом нет, ограничение спадает через час-другой и снова можно получать доступ к странице.

Я просто хочу понять как это все работает. Почему ограничение появляется только при использовании Jsoup.connect(), а если просто переходить по ссылке, всегда выдает нормальную страницу.

Comment: Тяжело что либо сказать не имея адресса самой страницы, попробуйте заменить .referrer("http://localhost:8080/") на .referrer(url), так же возможно где то на странице идет запись/чтение cockie которых у вас нет при отправке запроса

Comment: @Tiarait, попробовал менять реферер, без толку, а насчет куки не знаю как это проверить. Я отредактировал свой вопрос, теперь с конкретным примером адреса страницы.